# jquery invoke in code behind not working

Tags: jquery, .net

Im trying to invoke custom jquery which will toggle iframe-div visibility. Its working when invoke direct from button onclick  but not in code behind.

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    myfuncion01=function(){ 
        var myframe = window.parent.document.getElementById('myframe01');
        var vr_mydiv01 =$(myframe).contents().find('#div01');

        $(vr_mydiv01).hide();
    }

});
```

HTML Markup

```
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="myfuncion01();" />
```

Code Behind

```
 ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page.GetType(), "hwnd_appData01", "<script type='text/javascript'>myfuncion01(); </script> ", false);
```

What did I missed? Thanks.

Comment: Supposing the missing quote isn't a question composing error, you should try to use an editor having code colorization.

Comment: What is this- ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript

Comment: @AbhishekSaha See link in my answer (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You missed a quote.

```
var myframe = window.parent.document.getElementById(myframe01');
```

should be

```
var myframe = window.parent.document.getElementById('myframe01');
```

Also write the function outside document.ready or remove it. Its not required for functions.

```
    myfuncion01=function(){ 
    var myframe = window.parent.document.getElementById('myframe01');
    var vr_mydiv01 =$(myframe).contents().find('#div01');

    $(vr_mydiv01).hide();
}
```

Comment: I missed the single quote on posting, but that is not the error otherwise it will not work in button onclick().

Answer (score 0):

http://www.aptana.com/ (or any js IDE)... human perception of "missing chars" is easy to deceive.

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y.aspx) :

> The script block added by the RegisterStartupScript method executes
>   when the page finishes loading but before the page's OnLoad event is
>   raised. The script blocks are not guaranteed to be output in the order
>   they are registered.

When the script registered using RegisterStartupScript is executed, the function doesn't yet exist.

Take the function definition out of the ready callback and put it in your header :

```
<head>
...
<script>
function myfuncion01(){ 
    var myframe = window.parent.document.getElementById('myframe01');
    $(myframe).contents().find('#div01').hide();
}
</script>
</head>
```

Comment: Excellent. Also Im missing the script tag in ClientScriptManager script parameters.